# Mysql query returns null value even no rows exists

Tags: java, mysql, database

The following  query returns null while there are no rows exists in the database.

```
String sql ="select SUM(amount) from due where date='"+jyearChooser.getYear()+"%'";
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Post some data from the table `due` in your question to see where is the issue. Also, add code related to `jyearChooser.getYear()`

Comment: If the question is about why it returns anything then this is how aggregation functions work. If the question is how to make it returns 0 instead of `null` then check this question stackoverflow.com/questions/7602271/how-do-i-get-sum-function-in-mysql-to-return-0-if-no-values-are-found

Answer (score 0):

check the datatye of amount in Db whether its in integer or varchar